# 'characters' is unavailable: Please use String directly . I have a problem with this

Tags: swift

```
private func setTextWithTypingAnimation(_ typedText: String, _ attributes: Dictionary<NSAttributedString.Key, Any>?, _ charInterval: TimeInterval, _ initial: Bool, _ dispatchID: Int) {

        guard typedText.characters.count > 0 && currentDispatchID == dispatchID else {
            typingOver = true
            typingStopped = false
            return
        }

        guard typingStopped == false else {
            stoppedSubstring = typedText
            return
        }

        if initial == true {
            super.text = ""
        }

        let firstCharIndex = typedText.characters.index(typedText.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
```

Comment: Use direct (typedText.count)

Comment: Removing `.characters` should work just the same.

Comment: What “problem”? Did you check these related questions? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+%27characters%27+is+unavailable%3A+Please+use+String+directly

Comment: what is the error

Answer (score 4):

As Swift 4 introduced changes on string API.

You can use `typedText.isEmpty` instead of `typedText.characters.count > 0` and for

```
let firstCharIndex = typedText.index(typedText.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

character is deprecated. You can use string directly like this.

```
guard typedText.count > 0 else {
    return
}

let firstCharIndex = typedText.index(typedText.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a for in loop. For example:

```
let users = ["Jorge", "John", "Jose"]

for user in users {
    print(user)
}
```

Your output should be:

```
Jorge
John
Jose
```